# How Can I Archive A Facebook Conversation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I have a rather long conversation on Facebook. I scrolled up so much that my computer has 5+ second spikes every time it adds another batch of messages. I still have another 25k to go. Time will not permit saving especially if the spikes continue at that scale.

**What can I use to archive my conversations including all text, links and images/attachments (if possible)?**

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to 'Account Settings'
2. Click on 'Download a copy of your Facebook data' from bottom of General section
3. Then click 'Start My Archive' -- It may take a little while for gather your photos, wall posts, messages, and other information. (Usually 20 to 60 minutes)
4. Once Archive generated Download it.
5. Extract and open 'index.html' from downloaded folder
6. Now you can see 'Messages' on bottom of the page, click it.

Comment: +1 but it doesn't link or do anything with photos in conversations. I checked the html source I get nothing instead of a thumb, link etc to what should be a photo

Comment: It may not even be possible to get the photos when an API is used, so this may be as close as you can get.

Answer (score -1):

An easier method is to download and use SocialSafe (http://socialsafe.net).  Facebook messages are not saved by default in SocialSafe, so you will need to enable them by enabling them in Sync Settings in SocialSafe for your SocialSafe account.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work even though i clicked the option and sync'd it. It only shows my friends no messages